# Quadratic Equations word solving problems

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics, word-problem

I have three questions if you can solve them please show all of your work.

The height of Isosceles triangle is 2/3 of base. Find the sides and the height of this triangle if the area is 48cm^2.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there are three questions.

Comment: okay i will delete two of them

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I solved the first one but at this I havent tried yet anything.

Comment: I'll edit if I do any work on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A = (1/2) base * height = 48

height = (2/3) base.

You have two equations and two unknowns.  From here, you “plug and chug”.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!